# In Koa.js upload file and read the upload stream while its still being uploaded

Tags: node.js, file-upload, upload, koa, koa2

I want to write a REST API in Koa.js which will be used to upload a CSV file from the client side html file and while its is still being uploaded (meaning while upload is in progress and not yet completed), I want to read the upload stream and convert it to JSON to store it in DB.

But how can I read an upload stream while its still being uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced the same issue. I've tried to use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-multer) from Koa but as I found it has only two options: store on the disk or keep in memory as a buffer. There is no way you can access the data as a stream.

After that I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jeffijoe/60c7a1fbf36a767477c82b9fe651fe48), hope it will solve your issue. Seems the approach may need a bit of rework in order to apply it to the real project. Anyway, this is not my code but will be happy to fix if there will be any issues.